Installing Ubuntu 24.04 from the TrueNAS system
when i try to install ubuntu 24.04 from my trueNAS system, It will get all the required file from the trueNAS, but at the point to start installation, i will get this error message: system program problem detected, do you want to report the problem now?

Do you have Windows installed on target computer?
